# ExtJS: Redirecting from one page to another page with post json data

Tags: extjs, http-post

At my application I need to redirect user from one page to another with sending POST json data between this 2 pages.

POST Im need because json data really long and I cant put it at GET-param

REDIRECT(NB not AJAX) Im need because at second page user get the file, generating by server (with json data what he gets).

Im searching for solution on ExtJS, but if there are no clear way it may be simple JavaScript.

Thx!

Comment: Do you need to open that new URL in the another tab or replace existing web application page?

Comment: replace existing web application page.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for necroposting, but I faced this problem and I've found this page. May be this will help someone.

You can create form using JavaScript and then call `form.submit();`

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "http://target.com");
form.appendChild(this.createInput("name", "value")); // your params
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

And createInput function:

```
createInput: function(name, value) {
    var field = document.createElement("input");
    field.setAttribute("name", name);
    field.setAttribute("value", value);
    field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    return field;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is the code you need:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'YourUrl.php',    // To Which url you wanna POST.
success : function() {
window.location = './account/login'; //the location you want your browser to be  redirected.
},
params: { foo: 'bar' }  // Put your json data here or just enter the JSON object you wannat post
});
```

Default method for sending data using Ext.Ajax is POST and you dont need to set the method to POST.

As soon as data is **successfully** submitted to the server, the page will be automatically redirected.

Comment: As I wrote here at my post (I dont need AJAX here - "REDIRECT(NB not AJAX)") because this code what you wrote at fist step send data and at second redirect coming. This is not solution because between this two steps I need to keep this data on server (DB, Session..) and I dont want to do what. But anyway thanx to you answer and please be more attentive at future.

Comment: What does NB mean?Why you believe that an AJAX redirect clears your session?PS:No offense but Please write in a more fluent English so we can understand you better.

Comment: NB - Nota Bene. Hmm... You are right about sessions variables - Im need to try that. (I dont think about it before) And yep - my English is not very good ,I know, at future I will try to write better :)

Comment: Simple post redirect is impossible even with ExtJS. This answer is wrong